# Youtube Data APIs with Javascript : direct upload of videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

Thanks to Youtube Data APIs documentation I am able to perform resumable uploads of videos with Javascript (with `XMLHttpRequest`). This is well documented. But there is a Javascript function (`youtube.videos.insert`) that is (in my personal point of view) poorly documented. After two days of research on the Internet, I am forced to ask for some help here.

Here is a sample of code

```
function defineRequest() {
if (!isAuthorized) {
  alert("You need to authorize the request to proceed.");
  return;
}

var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
if (!file) {
    alert("You need to select a file to proceed.");
    return;
}

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
    alert("file load completed");

    var data = reader.result;
    var fileStream = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    //var fileStream = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    alert(fileStream.size);
    alert(fileStream.type);

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
        media: {
            mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
            body: fileStream
        },
        part: 'id,snippet,status',
        notifySubscribers: true,
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                categoryId: 22,
                title: $('#title').val(),
                description: $('#description').text(),
                tags: ['hello']
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: $('#privacy-status option:selected').text()
            }
        }
    });

    request.execute(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        if (response === false) {
            alert("cannot upload video");
            console.log("Cannot upload video");
            return;
        } else {
            if (response.code != 0) {
                alert("cannot upload video");
                console.log("Cannot upload video");
                return;
            }

            var result = response.result;
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            alert("upload completed");          
        }
    });
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

}

And here is the error 400 I received (mediaBodyRequired). May someone has some clue?

```
{
"code":400,
"data":[{
        "domain":"youtube.video",
        "reason":"mediaBodyRequired",
        "message":"The request does not include the video content.",
        "locationType":"other",
        "location":"body"
    }],
"message":"The request does not include the video content.",
"error": {
    "code":400,
    "data":[{
        "domain":"youtube.video",
        "reason":"mediaBodyRequired",
        "message":"The request does not include the video content.",
        "locationType":"other",
        "location":"body"
    }],
    "message":"The request does not include the video content."
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)? It looks a lot different than you code.

Comment: You are right ! The documentation deals with the CORS way to upload videos. But there is also another API that allow you to upload video directly. As I am writing an internal documentation about Youtube API I needed to tell something about that API.

But for now, I will just mention the name of the API but won't describe anything about it cause I was not able to implement the feature with it...